# Revert changes made by Enable-PSRemoting

Tags: powershell, localhost

I created a script to revert changes made by Enable-PSRemoting based on http://blogs.technet.com/b/bshukla/archive/2011/04/28/how-revert-changes-made-by-enable-psremoting.aspx

When I enter the following commands in Powershell console, it works as expected, i.e it disables PSRemoting

```
c:\> winrm delete winrm/config/listener?address=*+transport=HTTP

c:\> Stop-Service winrm

c:\> Set-Service -Name winrm -StartupType Disabled

c:\> Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -Type dword -Value 0
```

When I execute a script

```
$scriptblock = {winrm delete winrm/config/listener?address=*+transport=HTTP}

$host_name =  (hostname.exe)

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ComputerName $host_name

Stop-Service winrm

Set-Service -Name winrm -StartupType Disabled

Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -Type dword -Value 0
```

I get unwanted output

```
WARNING: The network connection to local_computer has been interrupted. Attempting to reconnect for up to 4 minutes...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to local_computer ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to local_computer ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to local_computer ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to local_computer ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to local_computer ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to local_computer ...
WARNING: Attempting to reconnect to local_computer ...
WARNING: The reconnection attempt to local_computer failed. Attempting to disconnect the session...
WARNING: Computer local_computer has been successfully disconnected.
Invoke-Command : Network connectivity to local_computer has been lost and the reconnection attempt failed. Please repair the network connection and reconnect using Connect-PSSession or Receive-PSSession.
At C:\share\ps_disable.ps1:6 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ComputerName $host_name
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationTimeout: ([PSSession]Session5:PSSession) [Invoke-Command], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PowerShellNetworkFailedStartDisconnect,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

WARNING: Session Session5 with instance ID c7243bdf-bb9f-49c1-a1b0-9798969b0f99 on computer local_computer has been successfully disconnected.
WARNING: Session Session5 with instance ID c7243bdf-bb9f-49c1-a1b0-9798969b0f99 has been created for reconnection.
```

1. How do I eliminate "WARNING ....."
2. How to improve speed of execution instead of it taking 4 minutes, i.e. `Attempting to reconnect for up to 4 minutes`
3. How do I resolve Invoke-Command : Network connectivity to local_computer has been lost and the reconnection attempt failed.

Comment: Have you tried the -InDisconnectedSession switch for Invoke-Command? It may take care of all three concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving it to an answer so the question can be resolved.

Using the -InDisconnectedSession switch immediately disconnects the session that the command is run in so loss of connectivity will not stall the script or cause warnings. It will return a PSSession object that you can use later to get the results of the command.